# Value does not appear using crystal report in Windows 10 64bit

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have an issue in crystal report. I already developed report using SAP crystal report for visual studio 2012. 
I develop the report using C# languange for parameter screen, and then set debug > x86.
And then I run my report in windows 7 and it works fine. But when I try to run the report in Windows 10, the value does not appear in screen (blank value) but the label, report title, page title etc was appear.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue ?

*note : I have already install the runtime of crystal report version 13 for 32bit in Windows 10 pc.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your regional setting of your PC